# How to display SVN copy/rename operations in svn diff?

Tags: svn, command-line, diff

When I'm trying to show revision changes with `svn diff --summarize`
only deleting+adding showed instead of rename
and adding (without source) when its copy operation.

Of course, copy & rename was applied with svn commands
and I can see that there is copy in TortoiseSVN, 
but not from command line... How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

And my solution is...

`svn log --verbose`